# How to change specific element in a class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to edit a specific attribute from a class in css/JS/JQuery on hover of a different element, but I'm not sure how to do it
eg.

```
<h1 class="result">Lorium</h1>
<h1 class="result">Ipsum</h1>
<h1 class="result">Dolor</h1>
<img src="example.png" class="images"/>
<img src="example.png" class="images"/>
<img src="example.png" class="images"/>
```

so that when I hover on one of the `<h1>` tags, it will change the `src` of the `<img>`, but the rest will stay the same. Would I do this in CSS, JS or JQuery? How?

Note: they have to be classes, rather than id's, because I am using PHP to call all these elements and they have to be styled

thanks,

a tired programmer

Comment: You'll need some kind of attribute to link the `h1` to its corresponding `img`, unless you use the index (i.e., the first `h1` corresponds to the first `img`, etc.), which could be foiled by intervening headers and images in the page markup.

Comment: Is there any link for H1 with image? for which H1 which image tag should trigger?

Comment: can you please elaborate a bit. You hover on `<h1>` it will change the `src` of the `<img>` but rest will stay the same. Rest of `<h1>` or rest of `<img>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you need to detect the hover / mouseenter on the H1 element with the class result.

I am going to assume that all your results have the class result.

```
$('.result:eq(0)').mouseenter(function(){
console.log("hello world");
});
```

Next you need to change the img src associated with the result - again I am going to assume all your imgs have the same class.

```
$('.result:eq(0)').mouseenter(function(){
    $('.images:eq(0)').attr('src','https://via.placeholder.com/150x150')
});
```

I would suggest you to write a function so that you are not having to hardcode the nth value of the class selector.

Further reading: https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/

If you are not using jQuery - similar logic but you will use document.querySelector('.result')[0] etc.

Further reading: http://mdn.beonex.com/en/DOM/Element.querySelectorAll.html

EDIT -- For nth value where n is the same index number for both result and images

```
$('.result').mouseenter(function(){
    var nValue = $(this).index();
    $('.images:eq('+nValue+')').attr('src','https://via.placeholder.com/150x150')
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this works very well. However, I am a noob at JQuery so what would I have to google to create a function so that the nth value of the class selector could be dynamic? Thanks :)

Comment: @SamBkamp - What are you trying to acheive here? Is it a case where these headings are going to be permanently placed on the page and will always be 3 (like in your example?) Or - are there unkown number of headings and images? Depending on your requirement - the approach will change. If it is fixed - dont bother with finding the nth element etc - just hard code it and be done with it. If on the other hand it is dynamic - then - how are you getting the links for the images passed back - are you using ajax? As there may be a better way of doing things.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the structure of your HTML does not seem really scalable. I wouldn't count on order of elements. I would instead rewrite the HTML into something as the following:

```
<div class="result-container">
  <h1 class="result">Result title</h1>
  <img src="something.png" class="image" />
</div>
```

And then to handle events using jQuery, you can do something as follows:

```
function onHoverIn() {
  const resultTitle = $(this);
  const image = $(this).parent().find('.image')[0];

  image.attr('src', 'something-hovered.png');
}

function onHoverOut() {
  // same logic
}

$('.result-container .result').hover(onHoverIn, onHoverOut);
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks! How would I make it so that the nth term in the array of classes is dynamic?

Comment: @SamBkamp using my HTML structure or yours?

Answer (score -1):

In jQuery, typically you can change an image like this:

```
$(".images").attr("src","second.jpg");
```

But as you can see, because all the images have same class you probably won't achieve what you are looking for. You need something to differentiate images from each other if you are looking to map them to the header tags.

Since you have multiple, you are probably looking at something like:

```
$('.images').each(function() {
    //count the index and flip the image
});
```

Comment: The OP wants to change the `src` attribute on `hover` not for every element.

Comment: I get that, I'm pointing out how he can change an image for the lack of any try from OP. If he needs to know how to bind an event for hover, I'll gladly help.

Comment: Yes but that doesn't answer the question